# Unable to start electron through npm

Tags: npm, electron

I'm unable to start my electron app using `npm start`, but I'm able to start it using VS Code's integrated debugger .

my `.vscode/launch.json` contains the ff:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "electron",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Electron against the workspace",
      "appDir": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.js"
    }
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main.js",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
      "args" : ["."]
    }
  ]
}
```

both of them works fine.

but starting using `npm start` doesn't start the app:

> ```
> npm info it worked if it ends with ok
> npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
> npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
> npm verb cli   'start',
> npm verb cli   '--verbose' ]
> npm info using npm@6.4.1
> npm info using node@v11.0.0
> npm verb run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
> npm info lifecycle PRIVATE@0.0.1~prestart: PRIVATE@0.0.1
> npm info lifecycle PRIVATE@0.0.1~start: PRIVATE@0.0.1
>
> > PRIVATE@0.0.1 start C:\Users\Test\Desktop\LAN\Workspace\Code\PRIVATE
> > electron .
> ```

I've already thought of the possibility of wrong path but...

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "...",
  "homepage": "...",
  "main": "${workspaceFolder}/src/main.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "standard && mocha",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
}
```

I've already tried `"start": "electron src/main.js"` & `"start": "electron src/index.html"`

my `src/index.html` contains

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

*P.S* 
brought up Task Manager and `electron` shows up yet nothing appears on my screen, also shows no signs of changes in Mem/CPU usage. Unlike starting it in VS Code Debugger, it shows up instantly.

P.P.S 
If I missed up some information regarding the question, just comment it out, I'll try to include it as fast as I can.

Comment: ${workspaceFolder} might defined in vscode only, I think you should omit it in package.json

Comment: @rawel tried... no luck

Comment: May be worth trying to set your _start_ script in _package.json_ to: `"start": "node_modules/.bin/electron ."`

Comment: I don't believe Electron supports that version of Node. Try downgrading your Node to 10.11. Also what version of Electron are you on?

Comment: @pushkin that solved it!. many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using **npm run start**?

> **npm run** sets the NODE environment variable to the node executable with which npm is executed